# Need update eligible data from one table to another

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables. One is stage XYZ which contains raw data and the other is main table SKY in which most of the data is loaded as it is from stage.
 The stage table is a truncate load table.

I want to check out records between these two which are not same??? In other words , I want to know which all attribute/column value  is valid for a change from XYZ to SKY??

Be sure there are many columns in the SKY which is not available in XYZ.

XYZ has around 150 columns in total
And main table has 165( 15 are populated using some Informatica transformation from XYZ values, which i am not worried about)

Comment: post sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, The table XYZ should have a Auto Increment ID and the table Main will have the reference of that Auto Increment ID value. Once this structure is ready, informatica should always pick new records based on the value in Auto Increment ID column.

The select statement could be-

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ
WHERE Auto_ID > (SELECT MAX(Auto_ID) FROM Main)
```

Then you can apply further transformation on selected records for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I further there is an hash incremental table which contains the updated records. I used that to find out the records.